# Android, debugging MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent

Tags: android, android-camera, image-capture, android-camera-intent

I am trying to take a picture with MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent in the following way:

```
        String fileName = "testphoto.jpg";
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,
                "Image capture by camera");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                .putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI),
                R.id.capture_image_request);
```

Handling activity result:

```
        try {
            uploadedPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                                           .openInputStream(imageUri));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And after that I'm trying to show just taken image:

```
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_picture_thumbnail)).setImageBitmap(uploadedPicture);
```

And that doesn't work. After that I tried to open an input stream from that Uri:

```
final InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
Log.("mydebug tag", is.available());
```

is.available() returns 0. Why is that file empty???

When I tried to debug I found that Uri like "content://media/external/images/media/68" had been returned.
After that I hardcoded:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/68");

    Bitmap pic;
    try {
        pic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_picture_thumbnail)).setImageBitmap(pic);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
```

And that worked.

So I wonder why when I construct Uri manually - it works, but when I recieve a Uri of just taken picture - it doesn't? I have a feeling that when I access Uri of just taken picture, it isn't stored on a file system yet, that's why it's size is equal to 0 and can't be loaded into ImageView. But after a time (when I run my application again, with hardcoded Uri) file gets stored and works fine. Are there any ways to make a force flush of that file to a disk?